# Unable to connect to route Gateway?

Tags: networking, router, media

A previous router which I used for a long time it's WiFi died; only the WiFi. Therefore I had to replace the router. I have a network and only one of the computer can recognize the router, meanwhile another computer cannot connect to the router IP. I've tried almost if not everything when searching for the issue online; nothing works.

I've tried all of Windows10 automatic troubleshooting networking, none of those work. The problem is that the computer cannot connect to the router. I've done most if not all the ipconfig command from the /flushdns flags to /renew nothing resolves this issue ?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147653/discussion-on-question-by-christopher-unable-to-connect-to-route-gateway); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to install drivers from a year ago for the network adapter.